# React EmblaCarousel - Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help. I have this error  "Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render."
In codesandbox everything is working but when i place the code in my react app the error appears.
I am new to react so please explain how i can render EmblaCarousel...

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import EmblaCarouselReact from "embla-carousel-react";


import "components/partials/Carousel/styles.css";


function App() { {

  return (
    <div className="embla">
      <EmblaCarouselReact
        htmlTagName="div"
        emblaRef={c => (emblaRef = c)}
        options={{ loop: false }}
        className="embla__carousel"
      >
        <div className="embla__container">
        <div className="embla__slide">
        <div className="embla__inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="embla__slide">
        <div className="embla__inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="embla__slide">
        <div className="embla__inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="embla__slide">
        <div className="embla__inner"></div>
        </div>
   

        </div>
      </EmblaCarouselReact>
      <button onClick={() => prev()}>Previous</button>
      <button onClick={() => next()}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
};
}
export default  App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a two curly bracket in here (one inside one) while defining a function, which makes it a function inside another function, rather then defining a component.

The correct code is here:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import EmblaCarouselReact from "embla-carousel-react";


import "components/partials/Carousel/styles.css";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="embla">
      <EmblaCarouselReact
        htmlTagName="div"
        emblaRef={c => (emblaRef = c)}
        options={{ loop: false }}
        className="embla__carousel"
      >
        <div className="embla__container">
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </EmblaCarouselReact>
      <button onClick={() => prev()}>Previous</button>
      <button onClick={() => next()}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Still the same error;  Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in useEmblaCarousel (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Comment: This means, there is a problem with EmblaCarouselReact library. You can check this out on their website. But if you remove all of your code and just try with hello world, this should work.
This will help: https://www.embla-carousel.com/get-started/react/

Answer (score 0):

The `embla-carousel-react` version you're using is **highly outdated**. I would recommend you to update to the latest version in order to enjoy the latest features and make sure it's compatible with later React versions:

```sh
npm install embla-carousel-react@latest --save
```

And make use of the `useEmblaCarousel` hook instead:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react';

import "components/partials/Carousel/styles.css";

function App() {
  const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel({ loop: false });

  const prev = useCallback(() => {
    if (emblaApi) emblaApi.scrollPrev()
  }, [emblaApi])

  const next = useCallback(() => {
    if (emblaApi) emblaApi.scrollNext()
  }, [emblaApi])

  return (
    <div className="embla">
      <div className="embla__carousel" ref={emblaRef}>
        <div className="embla__container">
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="embla__slide">
            <div className="embla__inner"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button onClick={prev}>Previous</button>
      <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Don't forget to add the following to your CSS because this was done inside the legacy `EmblaCarouselReact` component before the `useEmblaCarousel` hook came along:

```css
.embla__carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

- Here is the [official documentation](https://www.embla-carousel.com/get-started/react/) for usage with React.
- Here is the official documentation [guide](https://www.embla-carousel.com/guides/previous-and-next-buttons/#adding-click-events-with-react) that shows you how to setup previous and next buttons.